# Preserving whitespace in PDF after XSL transform

Tags: xml, xsl-fo

I'm converting an XML to PDF using XSL transformation.  Unfortunately, it is not preserving the whitespace from the XML.  For example:

I want to convert this:

```
Test Line Data         : 0xAA
```

to PDF from an XML.  It looks fine in the XML, it has the 9 spaces between Data and : but in the PDF it shows

```
Test Line Data : 0xAA
```

Here is what I currently do.  After writing the data to the XML, I will perform the following:

```
XPathDocument xPathDocDiag = new XPathDocument(this.FileNameDiagXml);
XslCompiledTransform xslTransDiag = new XslCompiledTransform();
XmlTextWriter xmlWriterDiag = new XmlTextWriter(outputFO, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
xslTransDiag.Transform(xPathDocDiag, null, xmlWriterDiag);
xmlWriterDiag.Flush();
xmlWriterDiag.Close();
```

And then launch Apache FOP to convert the FO to PDF.  Like I said, unfortunately, the white space is not preserved when I need it to be.  I have tried manually adding   in place of spaces in the XML (find and replace) which does work after the conversion, but as we all know, the literal & can't be in XML so that option is out.  I have tried using XmlReader and then using

```
<xsl:preserve-space elements="*"/>
```

but again, that doesn't work either (no error or anything, just doesn't work).
The section of XSL looks like so:

```
<xsl:when test="Data != ''">
                <fo:table-cell text-align="left">
                    <fo:block />
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell text-align="left" number-columns-spanned="7">
                    <fo:block font-family="Courier New, Courier, monospace" font-size="9pt"><xsl:value-of select="Data" /></fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </xsl:when>
```

I have tried all sorts of attribute modifying to no avail.  Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add the attribute `white-space="pre"` to whatever `fo:block` you want to preserve the white-space in.

Example:

```
<fo:block white-space="pre">Test Line Data         : 0xAA</fo:block>
```

The attribute `white-space-treatment="preserve"` should also work, but when I tried it in FOP, it didn't.

The attribute `white-space-collapse="false"` also worked.

Comment: white-space="pre" did not work.  white-space-treatment="preserve" did not work either.  white-space-collapse="false" was the only one that did.  Thanks.

Comment: @dangerisgo - Glad you got it working. What version of FOP are you using? (Just curious.)

Comment: @dangerisgo - Ahh. I tested using .95 and 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.  http://groups.yahoo.com/group/XSL-FO/message/4128  When I put white-space-collapse="false" in fo:block, the whitespace is preserved.

Answer (score 1):

You can use space-after=5mm in the fo block tag. Example

```
<fo:block space-after=5mm>Something</fo-block>
<fo:block>SomethingSomething</fo:block>
```

The first line will create space of 5 mm after the text "Something".

Answer (score 0):

You may add space-after

```
<fo:block space-after=7mm>Your te</fo-block>
```