# Keep white spaces in the generated PDF with FOP

Tags: xml, xslt, whitespace, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm implementing `FOP` using `XSLT` and `XML` files where I want to keep the white spaces between words.
This is how my `XML`looks like:

```
   <lines>
        <line1>       My Creation       </line1>
        <line2>                                 address one AAAAAAAAAAA</line2>
        <line3>            This is the              address of creation</line3>
   <lines>
```

What follows is The result in the form of `PDF`:

```
  My Creation
  address one AAAAAAAAAAA
  This is address of creation
```

But I need it to be like this:

```
                My Creation       
                                          address one AAAAAAAAAAA
                     This is the              address of creation
```

Hence preserving all spaces. 
I used the following line:

```
  <xsl:preserve-space elements="*"/>
```

But to no avail.
I googled for solutions but in vain.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preserving whitespace in PDF after XSL transform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320622/preserving-whitespace-in-pdf-after-xsl-transform)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<fo:block font-family="monospace" white-space="pre" text-align="left">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</fo:block>
```

1. `white-space="pre"` will preserve the whitespaces
2. `font-family="monospace"` will equalize the spaces' sizes with respect
   to that of the characters'